# Type hierarchy based on string, with compile type check

Tags: c++, templates

I have a tree hierarchy of types, each defined by string, something like this:

```
com
com.example
com.example.shape
com.example.shape.triangle
com.example.shape.triangle.equilateral
com.example.shape.triangle.isosceles
com.example.shape.triangle.right
com.example.shape.quadrilateral
com.example.shape.quadrilateral.rectangle
com.example.shape.quadrilateral.squere
```

Types defines some data with dynamic parameters, that can be changed in runtime, so there is no way to create a compile time type hierarchy. So every entity is just a type name (string) and a list of parameters, and you can always register a new type in the system. Nevertheless a lot of types are predefined, and can be registered when system starts. In order to have the same experience with data created at runtime and predefined, I use this dynamic representation for both. For predefined types I would like to have a mechanism that can validate type name at compile time and I don't want to put strings directly in the code every time it must be used, it can be solved by defining string const expressions, but it is not very nice, something like this:

```
string some_type = "com.example.type1";
...
registerType(some_type, parameters_definition);
```

So I am thinking of a better way.

Another approach is to make something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Base {
  Base(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : name_(parent_name + "." + my_name) {}
  std::string name_;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Base& base) {
  os << base.name_;
  return os;
}

struct G : Base {
  G(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
};

struct F : Base {
  F(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
  G rectangle{name_, "rectangle"};
  G squere{name_, "squere"};
};

struct E : Base {
  E(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
};

struct D : Base{
  D(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
  E equilateral{name_, "equilateral"};
  E isosceles{name_, "isosceles"};
  E right{name_, "right"};
};

struct C : Base {
  C(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
  D triangle{name_, "triangle"};
  F quadrilateral{name_, "quadrilateral"};
};

struct B : Base{
  B(std::string parent_name, std::string my_name) : Base(parent_name, my_name) {}
  C shape{name_, "shape"};
};

struct A {
  A(std::string my_name) : name_(my_name) {};
  std::string name_;
  B example{name_, "example"};
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
  os << a.name_;
  return os;
}


int main() {

  A com("com");

  std::cout << com << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.triangle << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.triangle.equilateral << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.triangle.isosceles << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.triangle.right << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.quadrilateral << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.quadrilateral.rectangle << std::endl;
  std::cout << com.example.shape.quadrilateral.squere << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It is nice to use, especially having IDE with code hints, but unfortunately not easy do define. Every different tree level require new class to be defined with new members, that name corresponds with some strings.

I am looking for a better solution - simpler. It would be great to have it defined like some kind of template specialization, but I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions welcome :)
Regards, 
Piciu.

Comment: I presume this is not just a complicated way of printing strings. What is this naming hierarchy actually for? It would help to understand the underlying problem better, rather than just see your attempt at a very specific part of the solution as you see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach.

Here we create variable `name_token`s matching your `com` names.  We then sticth them together with a smart `operator/`.

There is a bit of boilerplate first, but the actual grammar is concise:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct or_trait : std::false_type {};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct or_trait<T0, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<bool, T0{} || or_trait<Ts...>{} > {};

  namespace names {
    template<class Tag, bool is_root, class...Parents>
    struct name_token {
      std::string name;
      name_token( std::string in ):name(std::move(in)) {}

      template<class Rhs>
      constexpr static bool is_valid() {
        return or_trait< std::is_same<Parents, Rhs>... >{};
      }
    };

    template<class Tag, class...Parents>
    name_token<Tag, false, Parents...> name( Tag, std::string s, Parents const&... ) { return std::move(s); }

    template<class Tag, class...Parents>
    struct name_token<Tag, true, Parents...> {
      std::string name;
      name_token( std::string in ):name(std::move(in)) {}

      operator std::string() const { return name; }

      template<class Rhs>
      constexpr static bool is_valid() {
        return or_trait< std::is_same<Parents, Rhs>... >{};
      }
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, name_token const& self) {
        return os << std::string(self);
      }
    };

    template<class Tag, class...Parents>
    name_token<Tag, true, Parents...> rootname( Tag, std::string s, Parents const&... ) { return std::move(s); }


    template<class LastToken>
    struct name_expression {
      std::string current;
      operator std::string()const { return current; }

      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, name_expression const& self) {
        return os << std::string(self);
      }

      template<class Rhs>
      constexpr static bool is_valid() {
        return LastToken::template is_valid<Rhs>();
      }
    };

    template<class Lhs, class Rhs,
      std::enable_if_t< Rhs::template is_valid<Lhs>(), int>* =nullptr
    >
    auto operator/( Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs ) {
      return name_expression<Rhs>{ std::string(lhs) + "." + rhs.name };
    }

    template<class Lhs, class Rhs,
      std::enable_if_t< Rhs::template is_valid<Lhs>(), int>* =nullptr
    >
    auto operator/( name_expression<Lhs> lhs, Rhs rhs ) {
      return name_expression<Rhs>{ std::string(lhs) + "." + rhs.name };
    }

    template<class Tag, class Token>
    struct uniquely_tagged {
        Tag tag;
        Token const& token;
        auto operator*( std::string n )&& {
            return name( tag, std::move(n), token );
        }
    };
    template<class OldTag, bool b, class...Parents, class Tag>
    auto operator*( name_token<OldTag, b,Parents...> const& parent, Tag tag ) {
      return uniquely_tagged<Tag, name_token<OldTag, b,Parents...>>{tag, parent};
    }
  }
```

We can then create the name tokens as follows:

```
auto com = names::rootname([]{}, "com");
auto example = com*[]{}*"example";
auto shape = example*[]{}*"shape";
auto triangle = shape*[]{}*"triangle";
auto right = triangle*[]{}*"right";
auto isosceles = triangle*[]{}*"isosceles";
auto equilateral = triangle*[]{}*"equilateral";


auto quadrilateral = shape*[]{}*"quadrilateral";
auto rectangle = quadrilateral*[]{}*"rectangle";
auto square = quadrilateral*[]{}*"square";
```

Now `com/example` works, but `com/shape` generates a compile-time error.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7212d952fb9486ca).

Bit ugly, consider not using this.

Comment: Hi, looks really nice. Using is a bit less comfortable (has no IDE support, like for members), but a WAY better defining. It is amazing that writing this code took you less time then me to understand it :)